# QML does not free a lot of memory, when dynamically created object has a parent

Tags: qt, memory-management, qml

I use `Component.createObject()` method to dynamically create an object. After that I delete the object using the `destroy()` method.
If I call the method `Component.createObject(null)` without parent argument (with null), then `destroy()` method frees the memory. If I call the method with some `parent` then `destroy()` method does not free a lot of memory. When creating a large number of objects, this results in exceeding the permissible amount of memory per process in Windows OS and leads to app crash.
Code to reproduce the problem:
`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Scene {
        id: scene
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

`Scene.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Item {
    id: scene

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var tileComponent = Qt.createComponent("Tile.qml");

        for (var i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
            var tile = tileComponent.createObject(scene);
//          var tile = tileComponent.createObject(null); // this works well, but I need a parent
            tile.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

`Tile.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100

    color: "orange"
}
```

The variant with parent uses 40 MB of memory after `destroy()`, without parent - 12 MB. If I continue to create and destroy such objects, the memory used continues to grow.
How can I dynamically create and destroy a lot of objects with parent avoiding the problem with memory?
I have tested Qt 5.9.1 (MinGW 5.3.0 compiler) and Qt 5.8.0 (MSVC 2015) on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I can only guess: Maybe the `parent` holds a reference to some wrapper, that is not deleted.

Comment: I tried to delete the parent itself (created the Scene dynamically and then called `destroy()`), but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal for Qt. You do not need to do anything about it. If you would continue testing, you would at some point see that memory usage stopped growing.

I would advise against using `gc()` because it really does not help anything. It forces Qt to do something that it will do automatically when it needs to.

> The garbage collector may be invoked manually by calling gc() within JavaScript. This will cause a comprehensive collection cycle to be performed, which may take from between a few hundred to more than a thousand milliseconds to complete, and so should be avoided if at all possible.

[source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#in-depth-memory-allocation-considerations)

Comment: I tested it now one more time: started to create new big portion of objects, when key is clicked. And you are absolutely right! Memory usage stopped growing on 130 MB. The first time, when I have tested a similar situation, I have created new objects very-very quickly, so there were not enough time to free memory and app crashed. Thanks, Filip!

Comment: Don't trust the automatic `gc()`. Call it manually when you seem fit, because it is really lazy sometimes and might decide it is less work to simply crash your app than doing the job.  Especially when you expect it to automatically `delete()` objects that are left without references.

Comment: One more problem was in my real code. It was connected with such situation in QML: `var testObj = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 60, 'd': 70}; for (var key in testObj) { delete testObj[key]; }` This code will delete only 2 elements, but not all. Pure javascript will remove all elements.

Answer (score 1):

QML doesn't really love releasing memory, but you can force it too by calling `gc()`, and it often benefits to call it in a sequence, it will keep squeezing extra memory even until the 3rd call.

On the upside, the used memory will be reused if you create more objects rather than allocating even more memory.

All in all, QML is a memory hog. Even creating simple, non-visible `QObject`s from QML has a [significant overhead](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60029). So I suggest, if possible, to use some C++ driven model rather than having thousands upon thousands of QML objects just sitting in memory, lazy loading, on demand loading - such techniques will do miracles for your memory usage.

Comment: It seems that `gc()` will release the memory only for objects without parents: [QML memory management](https://blog.basyskom.com/2015/qtws15-a-deep-dive-into-qml-memory-management-internals/).

Comment: `gc()` stands for "garbage collection" - it doesn't involve any objects, it involves memory that is no longer used by any objects. Keep in mind that QML is far from flawless, it is known to actually delete objects that are still in use https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50319 so don't expect miracles. I have tested with massive amounts of objects with parents and hundreds of megabytes of ram, and gc() works

Comment: I need to dynamically create and delete a lot of objects, but at the same time on the scene there can be only about 100 visible objects. So, I can create only some pool of objects and after that I will change properties of unused ones, instead of creating/deleting of new ones.

Comment: @BlackHoleTracer This idea is bad. You expect that Qt will release all unused memory as soon as possible, but Qt's approach is somehow different. It will release this memory only when it really needs to do it. You do not need to care about this. Create and delete thousands of objects every minute and your application will work fine.

Comment: The answer may depend on the platform.  On Android it is easy for QML to run out of memory.  For example, Audio files played just stay in memory until eventually error -19 on Android.  So if your app plays lots of audio files you will have to take over memory management.